# Error al hacer Update

Tags: c#, windows-forms, entity-framework

Estoy trabajando en una app windows forms, Entity Framework, tengo un error al momento de hacer el Update.

```
public void Update(T entity)
    {
        //Context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        TrySaveChanges();
    }
```

> Error:
>   Colocación de una entidad de tipo 'POS.EntidadesDominio.Talla' fracasado porque otra entidad del mismo tipo que ya tiene el mismo valor de clave principal. Esto puede ocurrir cuando se utiliza el método de 'Adjuntar' o establecer el estado de una entidad a "Sin cambios" o "modificación" si cualquier entidad en la gráfica tienen valores fundamentales en conflicto. Esto puede deberse a que algunas entidades son nuevos y aún no han recibido los valores claves de base de datos generados. En este caso, utilice el método de 'Añadir' o estado de entidad el 'añadido' para rastrear el gráfico a continuación, establecer el estado de no-nuevas entidades a "Sin cambios" o "modificado", según corresponda.

Tiene que ver como esta configurado el Context

```
public BaseRepository(PosContext context,
        bool autoDetectChangesEnabled = false,
        bool proxyCreationEnabled = false)
    {
        this.Context = context;
        this.Context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = autoDetectChangesEnabled;
        this.Context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = proxyCreationEnabled;
    }
```

Verifico si existe el registro en la db

```
public class TallaRepository : BaseRepository<Talla>, ITalla<Talla>
{
    public TallaRepository(
        bool autodetectChangesEnabled = false,
        bool proxyCreationEnabled = false) : base(
            new PosContext(),
            autodetectChangesEnabled, proxyCreationEnabled)
    { }

    public bool Existe(int codigo)
    {
        int result = Context.Tallas.Where(x => x.TallaId == codigo).Count();
        if (result == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Según ese resultado hago el Update o Create

```
public void Create(Talla entity)
    {
        if (_tallaRepository.Existe(entity.TallaId))
            _tallaRepository.Update(entity);
        else
            _tallaRepository.Create(entity);
    }
```

El error lo tengo en el Update que lo muestro lineas arriba

Comment: Hola Pedro, puedes poner el código de como obtienes la entidad que le pasas al método `Update` ?

Comment: Carlos Muñoz, ya modifique la pregunta.

Comment: Una pregunta Pedro, porque tener un update genérico? Por que en tu TallaRepository no tienes un método Update en el que se validen las propiedades que estás modificando, se obtenga del mismo Context la entidad y se la modifique sin recurrir a cambiar las configuraciones de `AutoDetectChangesEnabled ` y `ProxyCreationEnabled ` ?

Comment: Entity Framework lleva un registro de los cambios, para que quiero un contexto que este
vigilando los cambios, puedo hacer un contexto que no este vigilando los cambios y se 
ahorre tiempo. Entity Framework crea instancias proxy, para que crear clases proxy, con
fines de optimizacion le digo a Entity Framwork no generes clases proxy. Estoy utilizando el patrón Repository

Comment: Carlos Muñoz, tenía implementado el Context a nivel global y lo cerraba por medio de Dispose, ese era el problema, cambie a usar Using para que se encargue de cerrar la conexión y se soluciono todo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logre solucionarlo, primero tuve que crear un método Exist que me devuelva la entidad(si existe me devuleve la entidad y Actualizo y si es null Create).

```
public bool Exist(Expression<Func<Talla, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Context.Tallas.Any(predicate);
    }
```

Aplico según el resultado de Exist

```
public void Create(Talla entity)
    {
        if(_tallaRepository.Exist(x=>x.TallaId == entity.TallaId))
            _tallaRepository.UpdateTalla(entity);
        else
            _tallaRepository.Create(entity);
    }
```

UpdateTalla

```
public void UpdateTalla(Talla entity)
    {
        var local = Context.Set<Talla>()
            .Local
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.TallaId == entity.TallaId);
        if (local != null)
            Context.Entry(local).State = EntityState.Detached;

        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        TrySaveChanges();
    }
```

En UpdateTalla, si no me equivoco lo quito del contexto para poder actualizar. ¿A que se debe que pase esto?

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo como ejemplo el siguiente modelo

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // primary key
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

verifica tener definido la primary key 
para que puedas realizar:

```
Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
Context.SaveChanges();
```

de esta manera estarás apuntando correctamente el registro que quieres modificar.

Comment: Si lo tengo como primary key TallaId

Comment: y estas pasando el parámetro como TallaId ?

Comment: Así es, modifique la pregunta.